# Is it possible to take backup of MYSQL without command terminal?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

The following command is used for bakup of database using terminal

```
mysqldump –uroot –pmyrootpassword db_test > db_test.sql
```

How to use only mysql command line for backup of a database rather than command prompt, shell, terminals?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can , if you have FTP access then you can use [Adminer](https://www.adminer.org/)

Just download the file and place it in root and run the file via URL , you can export the database with available options in adminer.